# Cannot derive a Show instance for data containing UTCTime

Tags: haskell

I have data defined like the ff.:

```
import Data.Time.Clock

data D = D { ...,
             someDate :: UTCTime,
             ... }
         deriving (Eq, Show)
```

When I compile it, I get the ff. error:

```
No instance for (Show UTCTime)
  arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
               at ...
```

I already have the time-1.1.3 package which should already have this instance according to [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.1.3/doc/html/Data-Time-Clock.html).  My GHC version is 6.8.2.

Comment: Use ghc-pkg to check that you are actually picking up the right version.

Comment: Yes, 1.1.3 is being picked up.  I ran "ghc-pkg latest time".  I also compiled with the "-v" option and I saw the compiler actually hide the older version in favor of 1.1.3.

Comment: A Google search for `instance Show "UTCTime"` reveals that it's in `Data.Time.LocalTime`. This technique may be useful for similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't import each piece of the `Data.Time` suite separately. It's designed for you to import just `Data.Time`, and that will pull in just about everything that is commonly used.
Including the `Show` instance for `UTCTime`.

If you don't want that much namespace clutter, import just the symbols you need:

```
import Data.Time (UTCTime, getCurrentTime)
```

or whatever else. That's anyway a good idea - it protects you against name clashes
later on if the library gets updated and starts using a name that you have already
defined.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation lies. If you look at the source for [`Data.Time.Clock.UTC`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.1.3/doc/html/src/Data-Time-Clock-UTC.html), there simply is no `Show` instance for `UTCTime`.

Edit:

As newacct helpfully pointed out, there's an orphaned instance for `Show UTCTime` in `Data.Time.LocalTime.LocalTime`, so if you import that, your code will work.

Comment: it's in Data.Time.LocalTime.LocalTime though: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.1.3/doc/html/src/Data-Time-LocalTime-LocalTime.html

Comment: I emailed the package maintainer to clarify.  I'll post here as soon as I get a reply.

Comment: It's an orphan instance defined in Data.Time.LocalTime.LocalTime.  Importing Data.Time will give the constructor in Data.Time.UTC and the Show instance in Data.Time.LocalTime.LocalTime.